# How to host a website on localhost?

Tags: hosting

I have registered a domain http://ishaan.vv.si. I want that if I edit the files on my computer, then the changes are made to my site. Basically I want to host my site from my local computer on the  web.
Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Install a webserver
2. Expose the port it runs on (probably 80) to the Internet

   - port forwarding from the router
   - public IP address assigned to the computer running the webserver
3. Set up an A record for your DNS to point `ishaan.vv.si` to the IP address you are running the server on

Answer (score 2):

Use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com) to connect localhost with web end points

Answer (score 1):

If you want to host your site on your local computer. 
1. You need a static IP. 
2. A web server like IIS, Apache running on your local computer.

You need to change your named sever of your domain to your local computer.

Then you can setup your site.

[See how to setup new site on ISS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323972)

[See how to setup new site on Apache](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/solutionbase-setting-up-a-simple-web-site-with-apache-22/#.)